# MySQL Query - SELECT row count from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this table in my database

[image]

And I;m using this query:

```
SELECT cl.cl_id, cl.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM cl, st 
WHERE st.cl_id = cl.cl_id 
GROUP BY cl.cl_id 
ORDER BY cl.cl_id;
```

Because some cl_id value in st table not exits, the output just return where cl_id is on the st table. The query I need is like this:

```
SELECT cl.cl_id, cl.name 
FROM cl;
```

but implement this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM st 
WHERE st.cl_id = cl.cl_id;
```

but if in st table doesn't have all value from cl_id the value return to 0.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh I think that's today's second Tip of today.

Comment: @Strawberry, so embarrassing, you got me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  In your case, it would then be obvious that you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT cl.cl_id, cl.name, COUNT(st.cl_id) 
FROM cl LEFT JOIN
     st 
     ON st.cl_id = cl.cl_id 
GROUP BY cl.cl_id 
ORDER BY cl.cl_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

(based on Juan's answer)
Use `LEFT JOIN` and the `COALESCE` function, which returns the first non-null value from a list of arguments

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(st.cl_id,0)
, COALESCE(st.name,'Name Not Found')
, COUNT(cl.cl_id) 
FROM cl 
LEFT JOIN st 
  ON st.cl_id = cl.cl_id 
GROUP BY COALESCE(st.cl_id,0) 
ORDER BY COALESCE(st.cl_id,0) ;
```